# Introducing a new class in tensorflow python scripts

Tags: python, tensorflow

I am a new Tensorflow user. I am trying to implement a modified version of BasicLSTMCell to perform custom operations. I introduced a new class named 'BasicLSTMCellModified' in the script at tensorflow/python/ops/rnn_cell_impl.py. 
The class is defined as follows

```
@tf_export("nn.rnn_cell.BasicLSTMCellModified")

class BasicLSTMCellModified(LayerRNNCell):

     #Class description
```

Upon adding the new class, I tried creating an instance of the class in my test python script. But the class is not visible from the test python script. I have tried different things by importing different paths. But none of them has worked. Kindly help me in this.

Comment: can you provide a code fragment/folder structure showing how you tried to load the script?

Comment: Please format correctly using Markdown (use a code block) so this is readable.  Thanks!